# How would you design a program that preforms Ackermann's Function?

Tags: function, recursion

Hi I'm fairly new to CS and I am stumped on how to get this homework problem started. It's asking me to Design a function ackermann (m,n) which solves Ackermann's Function. It's asks me to use the following logic: if m=0 then return n+1 if n = 0 then return ackermann (m-1,1) otherwise, return ackermann (m-1,ackermann (m,n-1)). Also does anyone have any good links for a better understanding of recusion? 
-Thanks

Comment: At least take a programming language!

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function declaration in program languages are very similar to algorithm pseudo codes.

Here is a simple `ackerman` function in python:

```
def ackermann (m, n):
    if m==0:
        return n+1
    elif n==0:
        return ackermann(m-1,1)
    else:
        return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))

print ackermann(3,3)
```

You can give any number you want but be aware that ackermann is an extremely recursive function and may exceed the stack bounds with little numbers.

And here is a good material for recursive understanding. [stanford intro to recursive](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/cs106b/chapters/05-intro-to-recursion.pdf)